# ComboBox ListFillRange VBA

Tags: vba

I am quite new to VBA for Excel and i'm trying to make a `ComboBox` and fill it with values from a specific range. I got the code for the box itself somewhere from the internet and added some things as the `ListFillRange` to it. Problem is that the list of the `ComboBox`only has the value of the first cell of the range I specify, whatever I try. I searched all over the internet and can't find a solution to this. I put the box in a separate macro just to test what is the problem. Here is the code:

```
Sub testme()

Dim box As OLEObject
Dim myRng As Range

'combobox from the Control toolbox toolbar
Set myRng = ActiveSheet.Range("a25")
With myRng
Set box = .Parent.OLEObjects.Add _
(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
Link:=False, _
DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
Left:=.Left, _
Top:=.Top, _
Width:=.Width, _
Height:=.Height)
End With
box.LinkedCell = "b20"
Dim gebied As Range
Set gebied = Range("$A$4:$I$4")
box.ListFillRange = gebied.Cells.Address
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ListFillRange needs to be in one column. I don't think there's a way around that for a WorkSheet ActiveX `ComboBox`, but I could be wrong. Try something like:

```
Set gebied = Range("$A$4:$A$11")
box.ListFillRange = gebied.Cells.Address
```